# Unable to resolve import error from PyCaret

Tags: pycaret

I am trying to install pycaret by creating an environment in anaconda (python 3.8). Everything is fine except when i tried to from `pycaret.classification import *` i shows an error despite the fact that i have installed all dependencies:

`ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2'. DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install Jinja2.`
I tried refreshing the kernel and reinstalling Jinja2 but the error remains. May i know how could i overcome it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had same issue in colab, I fixed it by forcing the `markupsafe` version:

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

After this, the next imports worked as before

```
import jinja2
```

```
pycaret.classification import *
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with this one for a few days. Have an updoot.

Comment: Works here too. But after install markup, you need to "restart > 'restart runtime'" to this changes apply.

Comment: worked here too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and fixed it by:

```
!pip install pycaret==2.3.10 markupsafe==2.0.1 pyyaml==5.4.1 -qq
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
So when I ran the above statement it gave me some compatibility error.
So I executed the following statement

```
!pip uninstall imgaug && pip uninstall albumentations && pip install git+https://github.com/aleju/imgaug.git
```