# Error when installing pycaret (jinja2) on Colab

Tags: classification, pycaret

I'm trying to use pyCaret on Colab. This is the setup:

```
!pip install pycaret
from pycaret.classification import *
grid = setup(data=s, target=s.columns[-1], html=False, silent=True, verbose=False)
best_model = compare_models()
```

However, I get this error on from pycaret.classification import *:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2'. DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install Jinja2.
```

I've already followed this instruction unsuccessfully. [Unable to resolve import error from PyCaret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090241/unable-to-resolve-import-error-from-pycaret)

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else facing this issue and if its not work like author said try ;

```
pip install pycaret --user
```

after execution of code chunk done click *restart runtime button. after install if its succesfully import libraries skip markupsafe phase.

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

after execution of code chunk done click *restart runtime button.

```
import jinja2
from pycaret.classification import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just install Jinja2 manually to solve this problem:

https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/2490